Preferred way to pass loading state from useMutation to parent in React
Currently I have a child component making use of useMutation (Apollo). However I need to access the loading state in the parent component. Which of these three options is preferred? Maybe there are even better options (context or global state)? Would any of these be an antipattern / not done?
1) Moving the mutation up to the parent and passing a handler/trigger down to the child
// parent.js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [yourMutation, { loading }] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION);

  const handleMutation = async (data) => {
    try {
      await yourMutation({ variables: data });
      // Mutation successful, do something
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent handleMutation={handleMutation} />
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

// child.js
const ChildComponent = ({ handleMutation }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    const data = { /* Your data here */ };
    handleMutation(data);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Trigger Mutation</button>
  );
};

2) Keep the loading state in the parent and pass a handler to update the state to the child (keep mutation in the child)
// parent.js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleLoading = (isLoading) => {
    setLoading(isLoading);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent handleLoading={handleLoading} />
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

// child.js
const ChildComponent = ({ handleLoading }) => {
  const [yourMutation, { loading }] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION);

  const handleMutation = async () => {
    handleLoading(true); // Set loading state to true before mutation
    try {
      await yourMutation(); // Execute mutation
      // Mutation successful, do something
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    } finally {
      handleLoading(false); // Set loading state to false after mutation
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleMutation}>Trigger Mutation</button>
    </div>
  );
};

3) Same as 2 but use useEffect to call the handler
(This is probably some React antipattern?)
// child.js
const ChildComponent = ({ handleLoading }) => {
  const [yourMutation, { loading }] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION);

  useEffect(() => {
    // When the loading state changes, notify the parent component
    handleLoading(loading);
  }, [loading, handleLoading]);

  const handleMutation = async () => {
    try {
      await yourMutation(); // Execute mutation
      // Mutation successful, do something
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleMutation}>Trigger Mutation</button>
    </div>
  );
};

3) feels convenient but there is an useEffect which isn't completely necessary as proven by 2). Would this be unsafe?
I am undecided if 1) or 2) is better. 1) allows for a 'dumber' child and doesn't put the logic in two files.
Which of these three options is preferred? Maybe there are even better options? Would any of these be an antipattern / not done?
All three options do work, I want to know which would be best and why.

My preference would be to move the mutation up to the parent. The keeps the flow of data moving down from the parent.

In my opinion, The best way is to handle mutation inside the parent component and pass the data and the loading state as props to the child component. Using this method, you have complete control over the child component.
